# Center align view without overlapping with other views on Android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple Android view with two children, and I want to center align the second one with the parent, without them overlapping. With constraint layout, we can do:

```
<!-- First view -->
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

<!-- Second view -->
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

When the two views are short, we can get what we want easily:

```
----------------
| --------     |
| |Text  |     |
| --------     |
|              |
| -----------  |
- |Some text|  -
| -----------  |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

But, because both views can be arbitrary tall, and we don't want them to overlap, the second view needs to shift downwards when necessary:

```
----------------
| -----------  |
| |Text     |  |
| |Text     |  |
| |More text|  |
| -----------  |
- ------------ -
| |Other text| |
| |Text      | |
| ------------ |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

I tried adding `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first"` to the second view, but that doesn't work. Adding  a `marginTop` with the height of the first view doesn't work either because that will center the second view in the remaining space. Can this be achieved with constraint layout (or other layout)?

I also tried to do this programmatically by changing the layout constraint in second view's  `OnLayoutChangeListener`, but it doesn't seem to work (still overlapping).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you edit your question an add your xml you tried and a screen shoot of the issue or the expected output

Comment: the key part of the xml is already up there in the question, and the expectation is already illustrated.